# symfony : form generation takes a lot of memory

Tags: php, forms, symfony, caching, memory-management

In my symfony application, I am generating a form in order to parameter some ingredients.
I now face the situation where users start managing thousands of ingredients.

With only 200 ingredients, the php memory usage goes above the max 120Mo.

The following shows that the action stats with a usage of 50Mo and that creating the form alone takes 40Mo. It crashes if I try to render the view.

What can I do to avoid forms to take so much memory ?

My controller action :

```
/**
 * @Route("/set_ingredient_stock", name="set_ingredient_stock")
 * @Method({"PUT","GET"})
 * @Template(":FoodAnalytics/UserIngredient:set_ingredient_stock.html.twig")
 * @param Request $request
 * @Security("is_granted('organizer')")
 * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function setIngredientStockAction(Request $request)
{
    r('init : ' . ceil(memory_get_usage() / 1000000));
    $userIngredientManager = $this->get('user_ingredient_manager');
    r('manager : ' . ceil(memory_get_usage() / 1000000));
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User\User')->findUserWithUserIngredients($this->getPortfolioUser());
    r('user : ' . ceil(memory_get_usage() / 1000000));
    $setStockIngredientForm = $userIngredientManager->getSetIngredientStockForm($user);
    r('form : ' . ceil(memory_get_usage() / 1000000));

    if ($request->getMethod()=='PUT')
    {
        $formManager = $this->get('form_manager');

        if ($formManager->handleRequestAndFlush($setStockIngredientForm, $user))
        {
            $this->addSuccess("Le stock d'ingrédients à été mis à jour");

            return $this->redirectToRoute('set_ingredient_stock');
        }

        $this->addInvalidFormMessage();
    }

    $nonExecutedTasks = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Task')->getNonExecutedTasksQueryBuilder($this->getPortfolioUser())->select('COUNT(t)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    $nonReceivedOrders = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:MarketPlace\Order')->getNonReceivedOrdersQueryBuilder($this->getPortfolioUser())->select('COUNT(o)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();;
    $horizon = $user->getParameter(User::STOCK_HORIZON) ?: 7;
    r('small_variables : ' . ceil(memory_get_usage() / 1000000));
    $userIngredients = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\UserIngredient')->getUserIngredientsWithJoinsIndexedByProductIds($this->getPortfolioUser());
    r('user_ingredients : ' . ceil(memory_get_usage() / 1000000));
    $stocks = $userIngredientManager->getUserIngredientStocks($userIngredients, $horizon);
    ~r('stocks : ' . ceil(memory_get_usage() / 1000000));

    return array(
        'set_stock_ingredient_form' => $setStockIngredientForm->createView(),
        'non_executed_tasks' => $nonExecutedTasks,
        'non_received_orders' => $nonReceivedOrders,
        'stocks' => $stocks,
        'horizon' => $horizon
    );
}
```

The dumps:

```
init : 50
manager : 51
user : 61
form : 100
small_variables : 100
user_ingredients : 101
stocks : 105
```

EDIT :
The methods that generates the form just created a regular symfony form attached to the user who owns a collection of userIngredients generated by another type. There are 3 fields per userIngredients.

Comment: Something wrong with whole application, on start you have 50MB? I never exceeded 20MB on whole request. Just checked now one controller with annotation similar to yours, on init I have 5, after clearing cache it increased to 9 for first time visit.

Comment: arf, solving this might speed up my app quite a bit then !! any idea ?

Comment: xdebug or any other tool to profile your application.

Answer (score 0):

Not one user is waiting for a list of thousands rules (or items, forms etc). If there are more then about 25 rules then nobody wants to read them anymore.

You should better provide [pagination](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) and Filters

Comment: you're right, I'm still struggling a little bit with this because I have very custom data in my table which is generated from the query result, but after the query (for instance a stock evolution given production tasks of plannings with tree structure) So ordering this data means having calculated it all first... if you see a solution